# Measure and other properties of nodal domains of Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, elliptic-pde, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(\phi_k,\lambda_k)$ be the couple of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the the Laplacian operator on $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.
The nodal set of $\phi_k$ is the set $$\mathcal N_k = \{x \in \Omega: \phi_k(x) = 0\}.$$ The nodal domains of $\phi_k$ are the connected components of $\Omega \setminus \mathcal N_k$.

If $\Omega = [0,1]$, it's simple to check that $$\phi_k = \sqrt{2} \sin(k \pi x)$$ and $$\mathcal N_k = \{x = i/k: i = 1,\dots, k-1\}$$
and therefore the nodal domains of $\phi_k$ are $k$ intervals of equal length.

Does something similar hold if we take $\Omega$ to be a smooth (connected) domain of $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>1$? In particular, do the nodal domains of $\phi_k$ have the same measure? Can we say something about their shape? ... What is known about this topic?

Comment: No. Try the unit disk in the plane for starters. It is a good exercise that will shed some more light on your question. Try next the unit $3$-d ball, and you feel adventurous, try the unit $n$-dimensional ball. There is a rich math in these computations.

Comment: Also, try to check the literature perhaps. The nodal domains of Dirichlet eigenfunctions have been studied extensively.